# Why are numbers interpreted as a date when exporting to Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

When exporting results from BigQuery using the export to Google Sheets feature, some numbers are automatically interpreted as dates. For instance, the float 28.5 in BigQuery becomes 28/05/2016 in Google Sheets, and if I try to format it as a number, it becomes 42518. The floats 77.1 or 9.768 are exported as expected.

Is there a way I can avoid this (either in BigQuery or Google Sheets)? Or is the backend responsible for this?

Edit: here's a dummy query I used for my tests

```
SELECT
  date,
  SUM(FLOAT(metric))
FROM (
  SELECT
    "20141114" AS date,
    "77.1" AS metric),
  (
  SELECT
    "20141115" AS date,
    "28.5" AS metric),
  (
  SELECT
    "20141116" AS date,
    "9.768" AS metric)
GROUP BY
  date
ORDER BY
  date ASC
```

Comment: ive encounteted this before. the auto conversions depend on it will depend on your sheet day   format / language settings. best way ive found is to prepend a single quote before all cells when writting to the sheet. this will store all cells as  strings, but means you may need extra code to parse those cells later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Zig Mandel, it turns out to be a language issue.

Launching the export with display language set to English in general settings for the spreadsheet, the value "28.5" is not automatically interpreted, and I get the wanted result. The account I used for my first export has the display language set to French, which strangely changes the number to a date.

You can check the language settings by selecting File -> Spreadsheet Settings in your Google Sheet, where I assume the display language is the language for your Google account

Comment: Ah, interesting.  This would be a good issue to raise with the Sheets team through the "Help" menu on Sheets, if you haven't already.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the Help menu, and I will definitely raise the issue.